# Getting elements title's with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to retrieve the title of elements with the following codes

```
function highlight(elem) {
    var e = new Array();
    if (elem.style.border == '2px solid blue') {
        elem.style.border = '';
    } else elem.style.border = '2px solid blue';
    e.push(elem.title);
    var x = document.getElementById("test");
    x.innerHTML = e;
}
```

But it does not work. I have also tried passing 'this.title' in the function and displaying it, still does not work. Right now i am passing 'this' only.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you explain what you get instead? I don't see the point to set `e` as an array when it contains at most one item, and then it's converted to a string.

Comment: Please show your markup, and show how you're calling `highlight`.

Comment: I have changed it to elem.title. This happens: http://d.pr/i/rNg0
I have added an alert that displays the title. alert(elem.title) ; 
This is the code that populates the photo box : <a title="<?php echo $url;?>" href="#"><img class="photo-img" src="<?php echo $thumb?>" border="2" alt="" width="40" onClick="highlight(this)" /></a>

Comment: You are simply passing the wrong element or the correct element doesn't have a title. Please view the actual source instead of PHP code.

Comment: Well that suggests that `$url` is just an empty variable...

Comment: Its not. I echoed $url and it does have a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted in a comment:

```
<a title="<?php echo $url;?>" href="#">
    <img class="photo-img" src="<?php echo $thumb?>" border="2" alt="" width="40" onClick="highlight(this)" />
</a>
```

I can see that you are passing an `img` element with no title as elem.  You actually want to access the parent element's title using, since your `img` doesn't have a title, but its parent (the `a`) does:

```
elem.parentNode.title
```

Comment: Perfect. I don't know how i could miss that. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use `elem.getAttribute('title')`. It is browser agnostic solution.